# Any standard python libs providing split 'n join functionality on lists?

Tags: python, list, join, split

Are there any standard python libs that allow you to do stuff like this?

```
>>> [1,0,2,3,0,5,6].split([0])
>>> [[1],[2,3],[5,6]]

>>> [[1],[2,3],[5,6]].join([0])
>>> [1,0,2,3,0,5,6]
```

To me it feels like a pretty basic things that is needed quite frequently.
Note that strings support these methods by default.

Comment: Curious as to why you made your method arguments single-element lists `.split([0])`. Do you imagine that these functions should be able to split on multiple consecutive sequence elements?

Comment: @MattH That is similar to the split method for strings: `'spam'.split('pa')` returns `['s','m']`

Comment: Interesting. Anyway, I believe the answer to your question is: no, there is not a standard library function for splitting lists based on subsequences

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if any built-in functions are present to do this easily, but you can use itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain, islice, cycle
>>> lis = [1,0,2,3,0,5,6]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lis, key =lambda x: x==0) if not k]
[[1], [2, 3], [5, 6]]

>>> lis1 = [[1],[2,3],[5,6]]
>>> c = [[0]]*(len(lis1) - 1)
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(roundrobin(lis1, c)))
[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]
```

`Roundrobin` recipe used in the second one:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about standard libs, here's a little clumsy solution for `split`

```
>>> a = [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]
>>> ind = [-1] + [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == 0] + [len(a)]
>>> [a[i + 1:j] for i, j in zip(ind, ind[1:])]
[[1], [2, 3], [5, 6]]
```

Here's `join`

```
>>> l2 = [[1], [2, 3], [5, 6]]
>>> [i for x in l2 for i in x + [0]][:-1]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]
```